# lazyinitializationexception when CreateCriteria on child object

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I really don't understand this situation, I have two objects  Doctor and Appointment, these 2 tables are linked by a Id mapping table:

Doctor.hbm.xml:

```
<bag name="Appointments" table="AppointmentDoctor" lazy="true">
  <key>
    <column name="DoctorId"/>
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="Appointment">
    <column name="AppointmentId"/>
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

When I do this request, it works fine:

```
            var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Doctor));
            criteria.SetFetchMode("Appointments", FetchMode.Join);
```

The fact of adding SetFetchMode returns Appoinment correctly.

But as soon as I create a sub query like this:

```
            var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Doctor));
            criteria.SetFetchMode("Appointments", FetchMode.Join);
            
            //New sub query
            var appointmentsCriteria = criteria.CreateCriteria("Appointments");
            appointmentsCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("AppointmentState", AppointmentState.Cancelled));
```

the fetch on Appointment is no more done, and I get a lazyinitializationexception later.

Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Kindly refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264688/how-to-solve-hibernates-lazyinitializationexception/23265243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`criteria.CreateCriteria("Appointments")` overrides behavior you requested with `criteria.SetFetchMode("Appointments", FetchMode.Join);`. Inner joined collection criterias by default are not fetched. So you have to use left join:

```
//Collection criteria must be left joined to be fetched
var appointmentsCriteria = criteria.CreateCriteria("Appointments", JoinType.LeftJoin);
```

Or if you are using NHibernate 5.2+ you can use `SelectMode.Fetch` for fetching inner joined collections:

```
var appointmentsCriteria = criteria.CreateCriteria("Appointments")
                               .Fetch(SelectMode.Fetch, string.Empty);
```

More about `SelectMode` can be found [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/1599)